# Design employee matching system

Tags: design, architecture

This is a question that I got asked recently at an interview and was later told it was answering it not well enough which is why didn't get the job offer, interested to see what others would come up with.

A company has approximately 5000 employees and it wants to spread information throughout the company. To do this it wants to match up each employee with another random employee each week for them to discuss with each other in a short 20 minute meeting what they are working on.

The question was left as open as this and then I had to think up of what was the best technologies to use and any problems such as not having the same employees matched multiple times, timezone differences between employees, how the employeees get notified...

I have left what I did hidden below to not influence what you would think of doing

> I thought I could use a Python script which is scheduled by cron to run on a weekend and then be able to email each employee who they have been matched with. We would need a database which has a table with each employee's details to get there name and email. Then we would need another table to store who has already been matched up with who so far. The script would first read all the names from the database, try and match the employees randomly, then check the matches table for any conflicts and retry the ones that failed. I know this could potentially be inefficient as having to keep retrying possibilities but if running over a weekend I thought it shouldn't therefore be a big deal. I also thought it was better to leave off actually arranging the meeting and left that for the employees themselves

Comment: see [Why do interview questions make poor Software Engineering.SE questions?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6361/31260)

Comment: Is there a more appropriate place people typically put questions like this if it is not suitable here?

Comment: Nowhere at Stack Exchange I'm afraid.
["We already tried supporting those questions, we even gave them their own site. Sadly, it didn't work out..."](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200144/165773)

Comment: Didn't they suggest an alternative that may have ticked more boxes? Try and get detailed feedback, if you can.

Comment: Only the company can know what they think is a good answer to their question. As @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ says, contact them and ask if they will share their answer with you so that you might learn from it.

Comment: Though I suspect that what they were looking for was for you to talk about holding all employees in an array or list, picking the first one, generating a random number to pick another, removing both items from the list and repeating etc, and how that might be done efficiently. But, that's a pure guess. As I said, only they can know what answer they were looking for.

Comment: you would need 21 meeting rooms in constant operation with perfect timing

Comment: it will take each person 96 years to talk to everyone else

Comment: @Ewan Maybe the point of the question was to see if OP considered the feasibility of such a task..

Comment: @neil never tell the client they are wrong! more likely they thought the answer was too simple, you need functional programming, event sourcing a decoupled MQ layer and GDPR certification if you are going to charge the big bucks

Comment: @Ewan While you're probably right, I still suspect this is the reason for the rejection.  :)

Comment: Sorry I've missed something, what are you suggesting was the reason for the rejection, not realising the feasibility of what?

Comment: @user2802557 everyone meeting each other. its just pointless and expensive. it might have a been a meta test, to see if you objected to the requirements. But its really too hard to tell.

Comment: I wasn't led to believe at all that was what was being tested. It was definitely more of the technology of how you would implement such a thing